# How to connect github with visual studio code?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have started using Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/) recently . Started loving it. But I have some doubts regarding how to connect to Visual Studio Code to github.

I have one folder which contains 15 sub-folders and each sub-folder connected to a git repo. When I open a single sub-folder/git repo using Visual Studio Code, git operations working perfectly. But I want to open the root folder(containing 15 sub-folders) using Visual studio code, because i simultaneously work in all the repos. The root folder is not attached to git,
its just a folder on my local which contains all the repos.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately VS Code git features are working only if you open directly folder with initialized git inside. Otherwise it will not recognize it. At least this is true for V 1.5.2

Comment: True as of 1.10.2, and for the [foreseeable future too](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/396).

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure is messy omho. Even with other IDEs/editors and/tools you will have difficulties managing all that (not the number of subfolders but the structure itself). Check [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to see how to manage multiple git repos as one although I seriously doubt that VS Code supports this so you will probably end up using the good old terminal (at least you can have an embedded terminal in VS Code) or some graphical tool outside the editor. Still worth doing!